# How do I show that the derivative of the path $\det(I + tA)$ at $t = 0$ is the trace of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here, I'm taking $A$ to be a linear operator on $\mathbb R^n$ for $n>1$. Can you please tell me how to solve such a problem?

Comment: It's a nice exercise, but you should have the complete problem statement in the body of the Question, not relying on the title alone to give the important specifics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have

$$\det(I+tA)=t^n\det\left(A+\frac1t I\right)=t^n\chi_A\left(\underbrace{-\frac 1t}_{=X}\right)=t^n\left((-1)^nX^n+(-1)^{n-1}\operatorname{tr}(A) X^{n-1}+\cdots+\det A\right)\\=1+ \operatorname{tr}(A)t+\cdots+\det(A)t^n$$
and the result follows.

Answer (score 4):

Letting $B=I+t A$, and using the [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) of the determinant, in terms of the permutations of the set $\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$:

$$p(t)=\det(I+tA)=\det(B)=\sum_\sigma {\rm sign}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n b_{i,\sigma_i} \tag{1}$$

One of the terms of the sum consists of the permutation that picks the diagonal elements; this has the form:

$$(t\, a_{1,1}+1)(t\, a_{2,2}+1)\cdots (t\, a_{n,n}+1)=1+ \beta_1 t + \beta_2 t^2+\beta_3 t^3 + \cdots + \beta_n t^n$$
where $\beta_1 = a_{1,1}+a_{2,2}+\cdots + a_{n,n}={\rm tr}(A)$

The other terms in $(1)$ include at least two off-diagonal elements in the product, hence they include a factor $t^2$.

Hence, $p(t)=1+ {\rm tr}(A)\,t + t^2 g(t)$ where $g(t)$ is some polynomial; and the result follows.

Answer (score 4):

we will use the following facts:

(a) determinant of a matrix is the product of the eigenvalues,

(b) trace of a matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues,

(c) eigenvalues of $I + tA$ are $1 + t \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A.$

$\det(I + tA) = (1 + t\lambda_1)(1 + \lambda_2)\cdots = 1 + t(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2+\cdots) + \cdots = 1 + \operatorname{trace}(A) t + \cdots$

therefore, the derivative of $\det(I + tA)$ at $t = 0$ is the $\operatorname{trace}(A).$

Answer (score 2):

For small $t$, we have $\det (\exp tA) = \exp (\operatorname{tr} tA) = \exp (t \operatorname{tr} A) = 1 + (\operatorname{tr} A)t + O(t^2)$. (If the first equality isn't clear, use the fact that $\exp$ and $\det$ behave nicely under conjugation, and reduce the statement to Jordan normal form.)

Comment: You're basically restating what the OP wants to prove. =)

Comment: Sort of, but the relation $\det(\exp A) = \exp (\operatorname{tr} A)$ is well-known and broadly applicable. Besides, I was thinking of the OP's question in terms of the map $\exp:\mathfrak{gl}_n \to GL(n)$.