# How to show $\frac{d}{dt}(\det(I+At)=\text{Tr}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show $\frac{d}{dt}\det(I+At)\mid_{t=0}=\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\Tr(A)$? I can't find a easy way to prove that.

Comment: Did you mean that we should take the value of derivative at $0$? Otherwise this is not true.

Comment: @zhoraster yes, I mean that

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this is a special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202535/derivative-of-a-determinant-of-matrix.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, but here it is infinitely easier to prove.

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038236/how-do-i-show-that-the-derivative-of-the-path-deti-ta-at-t-0-is-the-t)

Comment: @GAVD Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to look at the coefficient before $t$ in the polynomial obtained by expanding the determinant. Now try to identify where the terms $at$ come from. You should note that all the off-diagonal elements contain $t$, so there should not be too many such terms.

You can start with $2\times 2$ or $3\times 3$ to get the idea if you still stuck.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Note that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is

$$\det(A-tI)=t^n-\mbox{Tr}(A)t^{n-1}+O(t^{n-2}) \; .$$

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean by O(t^{n-2})?

Comment: That's really a terrible abuse of notation, since this is correct for unordered fields. Don't use $O(*)$ that way.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Care to elaborate?